# HTML Shrinking and expanding table cells

Tags: html, html-table, width, cell

is it possible to tell a table cell it should shrink so it uses as less space as possible and on the other hand tell specific other cells to automatically expand to fill the remaining space?

Answer (score 1):

By default, `<td>` tags will be as small as possible. If you want the cell to remain a certain size even when the content is smaller, you can set the width of the `<td>` tag like this: `<td style = "width: 50px;"`. The cell will automatically grow larger when it needs to, but it will not shrink below the specified size.